# Does anyone know the name of this mechanical part?

Tags: technical-drawing

Does anyone know the name of this mechanical part?[image]

Comment: What structure/machine is it a part of? Is there more context?

Comment: "Froderick"  is its name.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty certain that this is not a mechanical part used in a machine. This - in all likelihood - is an exercise from a textbook to allow students to put a 3d project onto a 2d drawing.

If you really wanted to put a name onto it, its probably a **bracket** or **clevis bracket** or  a part from a revolute joint.

Comment: I thought it's a bracket too. Thanks sir

Answer (score 1):

This could be a machine stop designed to push a lever or cam with the ramp.

However have to agree that it may also be just a drawing exercise.